# how to show/hide moreNavigationController when back?

Tags: objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, navigation, uinavigationbar, uitabbar

My tabbar have more than 6 items,when I click [more] item,it will show other items with a tableview.

Then click the one of items,I hide the navBar use `setNavigationBarHidden:YES` in `viewDidLoad`,and I have a custom button click to back [more] use `popViewControllerAnimated:YES`.

When it back,the navBar still hiding,how can I show the navBar recover on [more] screen?(I need the EDIT button in [more])

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just call `setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES`, before calling `popViewControllerAnimated:YES`.

Answer (score 2):

I added this to viewdidAppear on my custom tabbar controller class
not the proper way to to do it but I haven't had any problems with it

```
tabBarController!.moreNavigationController.isNavigationBarHidden = true
tabBarController!.tabBar.isHidden = true
```